# Flex' VideoDisplay control does not open stream

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, video-streaming

I'm trying to make `VideoDisplay` playing media with *FlashDevelop*. Here's the source of my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.VideoEvent;

        private function pause():void 
        {
            if (moo_player.state == VideoEvent.PLAYING)
                moo_player.pause(); else
            if (moo_player.state == VideoEvent.PAUSED)
                moo_player.play();
        }
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Panel>
        <mx:VideoDisplay 
            source="bar.flv"
            width="640"
            height="480"
            maintainAspectRatio="true"
            id="moo_player"
            autoPlay="true"
            doubleClick="pause();" 
            doubleClickEnabled="true"
        />
    </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

The problem is when i build application and run it (unfortunately, got no idea how to run it without KMPlayer or Mozilla - Flash Player is a plugin afaik) i got no video. The movie file is in the same directory as application's "Application.flv" one. But if i reload application (within player or browser) a few times, video starts.

**So, here are my questions:**

- what's wrong with `VideoDisplay`
  component and how to fix this
  'non-playing'?
- what's the better way
  to execute application than running
  it within movie player or browser?

P.S.: please, do not get mad of my knowledge lacks - i began to use Flex nearly 30 minutes ago.

Comment: Welcome to Flex, I think you'll like it!  VideoDisplay has some known issues, can you please post what version of the Flex SDK you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Spark components, not MX components.  Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:VideoPlayer source="bar.flv" width="640" height="480" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but while the code with MX components runs once per five runs or more, your sample runs once per three runs. This seems to be more stable hehe, but mx:VideoDisplay could be reimplemented with custom interface more easily than Spark one.

Comment: er, What? The *biggest* different between MX and Spark is that the Spark components are completely skinnable.  Also, I would look at the net traffic since this should work all the time.  It could be a sandbox issue, caching issue or that the video just isn't loaded yet (or failed to load).

Comment: Please, read my question carefully: i'm trying to play video that is located at the same folder as the .flv file. And i'm running that .flv within KMPlayer and FireFox - both of them give the same sadly results.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever.  Of course your Flash needs to be run within a browser (or within the Air runtime). KMPlayer probably won't play your swf very well, but whatever.  Still, it doesn't go away from the fact that I'm correcting your statement that "VideoDisplay could be reimplemented with custom interface more easily than Spark one", which isn't true.

Comment: Again, what?! Spark is just an architecture (just like MX), built on Flex, which is a UI framework made with *Actionscript*.

Comment: I am sorry then - i am very, very new to all this technologies. Should try than, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's some issues with video display internally in the component.  One of the only flex components that's kind of poorly done in some ways.  Please don't let it discourage you from exploring Flex.

Create a custom component that extends it, create a file named CustomVideoDisplay.as with this code:

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.VideoDisplay;

public class CustomVideoDisplay extends VideoDisplay
{      
    [Bindable]
    override public function get source():String
    {
        return super.source;
    }

    override public function set source(value:String):void
    {
        super.source = value;

        play();
    }

    public function CustomVideoDisplay()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

}

Then add this into your root `<application>` tag :

```
 xmlns:local="*"
```

And for your video component, refer to it as:

```
<local:CustomVideoDisplay 
        source="bar.flv"
        width="640"
        height="480"
        maintainAspectRatio="true"
        id="moo_player"
        autoPlay="true"
        doubleClick="pause();" 
        doubleClickEnabled="true"
    />
```

Let me know if this doesn't do the trick for you!

Comment: Somewhy this reminds me Java =) But unfortunately, now CustomVideoDisplay even does not render video =( And the bug with 'non-auto-playing' did not dissappear =(

Comment: Can you try setting autoPlay to false, then call your source= in your onComplete event?  I think this should fix you up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i thought: my player will be ran at client-side of web project, and in FireFox that code runs successfully each of seven runs. I think this would be enough for testing and implementation.

Thanks everyone for the trouble-taking!